# How can I change the class of a child DIV with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<li>
   <a id="show">
      <div class="sprite-blank" ></div></a></li>
```

How can I use jQuery to change this to:

```
<li>
   <a id="show">
      <div class="sprite-balloon" ></div></a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('li a#show div').removeClass('sprite-blank').addClass('sprite-balloon');
```

also you can use `toogleClass()` :

```
$('li a#show div').toggleClass('sprite-blank sprite-balloon');
```

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect. You are right that the key is the address with an id of "show".

Comment: I'll accept but have to wait ten minutes as I can't accept yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.sprite-blank').toggleClass('sprite-blank sprite-balloon');
```

That would change all available `.sprite-blank` elements on the page, if you need to be more specific, just change the initial selector, like

```
$('a > .sprite-blank').toggleClass('sprite-blank sprite-balloon');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
$(".sprite-blank").removeClass("sprite-blank").addClass("sprite-balloon");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like that:

http://jsfiddle.net/yUaZe/

HTML

```
<li>
   <a class="show" href="#">Show
     <div class="sprite sprite-hide" >Test</div>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a class="show" href="#">Show
     <div class="sprite sprite-hide" >Ha</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.sprite-balloon {
    display:block;
}
.sprite-hide {
 display:none;   
}
​
```

JS

```
$('.show').click(
    function(event) {
    var that=$(this);
    event.preventDefault();
    that.find('.sprite').toggleClass('sprite-balloon');
    that.find('.sprite').toggleClass('sprite-hide');
    console.log(that);
    }
    );​
```